# Open a pdf file in my iPad application with text search option

Tags: pdf, ipad

I am ipad Application developer.I am trying to open a pdf file in my application with text search option. Is there any possibility to load the pdf file within the application?

Comment: I found the temporary solution for this. I used CGScanner to search the text in the pdf. It works good. But the thing is I have to highlight the searched text within the pdf.

Comment: hi manoj..can you please let me know if you are able to highlight the text..
i am also searching for the same

Comment: if you findout anything please let me know how u did it????

Comment: can you please post answer for the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

@ Manoj :

Visit this and download that code ,U will get solution http://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly open a PDF document using a UIWebView just like on the iPhone. I don't know if it possible to search for text on the PDF itself - it is definitely not easy.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `uiwebview.load` PDF on webview.

Comment: using CGScanner we cannot scan all the pdf's.
different pdf are encrypted in different formats. cgscanner will not extract the data from all kinds of encryption formats.
it will extract only from linear pdf's.