# Is there any framework to highlight  text on pdf file after rendering on the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf

I am trying to work on searching a word on the pdf which is rendered through the `drawLayer`. Can any one suggest how I should find a word on a pdf and the position (co-ordinates) of the word on the page? Is there any free framework to import or any libraries available? After spending more time with google I found some samples to search a word on pdf; those are fastsamplepdf from github, [random ideas](http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42.)

**MY WORK**
I seen fastsample pdf code; I understood only the parsing of the pdf to text using

```
+(MFDocumentManager *)documentManagerWithFilePath:
    (NSString *)filePath;
```

and

```
-(NSString *)wholeTextForPage:
    (NSUInteger)pageNr withProfile:(MFProfile *)p;
```

But I can't find how they are highlighted. Please can any one help me out with this. Please post some suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Refer

[PDF search on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097044/pdf-search-on-the-iphone)

[PDF Manipulation on iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234408/pdf-manipulation-on-iphone-sdk)

[Which are the pdf operators needed to do a search feature in a PDF in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686924/which-are-the-pdf-operators-needed-to-do-a-search-feature-in-a-pdf-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: thank you mihir..i ll see and try to implement.upto now i tried pdf parsing and achieved so i can navigate to which pages the word contains...