# need to fetch a text from a PDF file in iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to fetch a text from a PDF file. Is there any PDF parsers code available for iPhone/iPad OS which can gives text from PDF ?

Or any PDF parsers which will convert PDF file text in XML format on iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

below links you can give the exact root please find
[TEXT HIGHLIGHT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering-on-the-ipho)

[Sample code](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)